# Rails: Not ember, not JS responses, but something in-between

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, data-binding, ember.js

I am developing a standard rails application, and so far I haven't used any AJAX, just good ol' HTML. My plan is to iteratively add "remote" links and all that kind of stuff and support for JS responses, because I know that generating JS server side is very very evil, but I find it to be very handy as well, easy, fast and it makes the application snappy enough and i18n comes out-of-the-box.

Using a pure JSON approach would be lighter, but needs lots of client-side coding.

Now imagine that in this application users have a mailbox, and since the idea is that they will be able to do most or even all of the actions without reloading the page, the mailbox counter will never change unless they refresh the page manually.

So, here comes the question: Which is the best way to handle this?

1. I thought about using Ember (for data binding), and sharing views with rails, via some sort of handlebars implementation for ruby. That would be quite awesome, but not very transparent for the developer (me). Although I guess that I only need to write handlebars views that will be used by ember, the rest can still be written in their original format, no?
2. Another option might be to use some sort of event system (EventSource maybe?), and just go with handy the JS views approach, and listen to those events. I guess those should be JSON objects, and the client must be coded to be able to handle them. This seems a bit cumbersome, and I need a solution for heroku (faye?), which is where my app is hosted. Any hints?

I think that the ember approach is the more robust one, but seems to be quite complex as well, and I don't want to repeat myself server and client side.

**EDIT:**

I have seen [this](http://layervault.tumblr.com/post/30932219739/rails-in-realtime), which is more or less the option #2.

Answer (score 0):

One of the advantages of using a JavaScript framework is that the whole application can be concatenated and compressed into one JavaScript file. Provided that modern browsers aggressively cache JavaScript, the browser would no longer need to request those assets after initial page load.

Another advantage of using a JavaScript framework is that it requires you to be a consumer of  your own API. Fleshing out the application's API for your own consumption might lend to less work in the future if there is a possibility of mobile applications or 3rd parties having access to it.

If you do not need your application to respond to every request with an equivalent HTML response, I think a compelling case could be made for using a JavaScript framework.

Many of those benefits might be lost if your application needs to respond to every request with an equivalent HTML template. The Ember core has been relatively vocal and in opposition to supporting this style of progressive enhancement. Considering the tools for using a JavaScript framework in this way are relatively unstable and immature, I might be prone to using option 2 to accomplish this.